# How to distinguish between the two states when the app enters the background actively and when it jumps to a third-party app?

Tags: ios, swift, state

Scenario 1: APP A clicks the home button or actively enters the background;
Scenario 2: APP A executes [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: When jumping to a third-party APP, APP A also enters the background;

The applicationWillResignActive: and applicationDidEnterBackground: methods will be executed when scene 1 and scene 2 enter the background

Question: How do I differentiate between these two states? That is, how do I know whether APP A is scene 1 or scene 2 when it is in the background?

The applicationWillResignActive: and applicationDidEnterBackground: methods will be executed when scene 1 and scene 2 enter the background

Comment: You can't tell by observing state transition. There is no difference in the two scenarios. In the case where your app opened another app via a url scheme, you know that you did it.

Comment: If it is your app’s code that is calling openURL in scenario 2 (as opposed to a 3rd party library) then you know when and where that code is executed and can do whatever you need to do. If you need to do something for scenario 1 then that is more difficult. You could maybe set a global flag when scenario 2 occurs and clear the flag in willResignActive. If willResignActive is called when the flag is not set, it’s scenario 1 (or some other action that triggers the same state change).

Comment: you can track the open URL state in a Global State, then check it on applicationWillResignActive, and reset it right after that

Comment: If in the middle of [UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL, I immediately click the home button to enter the background, which will also enter applicationWillResignActive, which will make it difficult to distinguish between scene 1 and scene 2